# How to access AWS service Open search Domain CLuster Nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-elasticsearch

I have one AWS service enabled i.e. Amazon OpenSearch Service in which I have domain & that has cluster 2 Master Nodes & 4 Nodes . How can i ssh the nodes as unable to find IP on the page

I tried searching for IP address of Node but didnt find in AWS Open search console page

Can any one help in accessing the one of the node i have to Install elasticdump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing nodes in Amazon OpenSearch Service (formerly known as Amazon Elasticsearch Service) via SSH is not possible, as AWS does not provide direct access to individual nodes in managed services like OpenSearch. This is by design, for security and management reasons. Managed services are intended to abstract away the underlying infrastructure, so users don't have to manage it directly.